# Checking internet connectivity using QtNetwork and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtnetwork

I'm trying to check network connectivity the hard way using `QtNetwork` but can't figure out how to do it properly. This is the code I'm working on it seems that neither `finished` nor `error` signals are called. What I'm missing here?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtNetwork, QtWidgets


class CheckConnectivity:
    def __init__(self):
        url = QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com/")
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
        net_manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.res = net_manager.get(req)
        self.res.finished.connect(self.processRes)
        self.res.error.connect(self.processErr)
        self.msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()

    def processRes(self):
        if self.res.bytesAvailable():
            self.msg.information(self, "Info", "You are connected to the Internet.")
        else:
            self.msg.critical(self, "Info", "You are not connected to the Internet.")
        self.msg.show()
        self.res.close()

    def processErr(self, *args):
        print(*args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ic = CheckConnectivity()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is caused because `net_manager` is removed, remember that a variable only exists in the context where it was created, in your case `net_manager` is a local variable that will be deleted when the `__init__` method ends.

```
class CheckConnectivity(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        url = QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com/")
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
        self.net_manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.res = self.net_manager.get(req)
        self.res.finished.connect(self.processRes)
        self.res.error.connect(self.processErr)
        self.msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def processRes(self):
        if self.res.bytesAvailable():
            self.msg.information(None, "Info", "You are connected to the Internet.")
        self.res.deleteLater()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError)
    def processErr(self, code):
        self.msg.critical(None, "Info", "You are not connected to the Internet.")
        print(code)
```

It is advisable to use the `pyqtSlot()` decorator since its use helps the application to be a little faster and consume less memory but for this the class must inherit from `QObject`.

Comment: @ellaynesc thanks for valuable advices and priceless contributions to my code. The code works fine but how to reduce the amount of timeout. Now it takes 4-5 seconds for the critical message to pops up

Comment: @eyllansec thanks i will go with `QTimer`. Are you aware of any up-to-date resource on pyqt5?

Comment: @eyllansec any book or video or anything you recommend to read or watch on pyqt5?